# What is in the Lockless Box?

Tags: the-kingkiller-chronicle, the-wise-mans-fear

In the novel *The Wise Man's Fear (The Kingkiller Chronicle: Day Two)*, the Lockless have a box that cannot be opened, and so Kvothe is sent to discover a way inside.

What clues do we have at what is inside of that box?

Comment: We don't know, and presumably won't until Patrick Rothfuss tells us.

Comment: It's a fascinating question, but not one for this site, where speculation is off-topic. Unless you can rephrase it as something like "What evidence is there in volumes 1 & 2 as to what might be in the box".

Comment: Thanks for the edit; I have retracted my close vote as the question can now be answered without speculation.

Comment: http://kingkiller.wikia.com/wiki/Loeclos_Box - Short answer, no-one known and Rothfuss hasn't spilled the beans yet. It's not even been confirmed that it's actually a box.

Comment: @Richard You should turn your comment into an answer; that way it can be searched on. Comments are invisible to Stack Exchange search.

Comment: Kvothe doesn't get sent away to discover a way inside. though he does take a great personal interest.

Answer (score 3):

I speculate from context clues that the box contains something related to Felurian's tale, as well as the Mercenary's tale, about someone who captured the name of the moon and placed it in a box; which is why the moon goes between the Fae world and the human world.

Comment: giving this the speculative correct answer until its confirmed or refuted in book 3.

Comment: As I pointed out in my comment; A) There's no indication of the box's contents (other than by supposition) and B) It's not even been confirmed that it's an actual box; http://kingkiller.wikia.com/wiki/Loeclos_Box

Comment: speculative or not, i love this answer.

Answer (score 2):

When Kvothe stumbles across a traveling group of entertainers that were a little bad off due to their bear dying of a dog bite gone sour, there was a boy who recited a riddle about the Lackless family:

> *Seven things stand before
>
>   The entrance to the Lackless door.
>
>   One of them a ring unworn
>
>   One a word that is forsworn
>
>   One a time that must be right
>
>   One a candle without light
>
>   One a son who brings the blood
>
>   One a door that holds the flood
>
>   **One a thing tight-held in keeping**
>
>   Then comes that which comes with sleeping.*
>
> <sub>*Wise Man's Fear*, chapter 108</sub>

I know this isn't the appropriate place for speculation, but there are subtle hints in his books, that will later be revealed no doubt, giving the reader a bit of foresight. I strongly believe the riddle told to Kvothe by this boy is obviously what is needed to open the Lackless family's door of stone, as there is sometimes a strong truth behind the little riddles and songs the children chant about. I believe it was the Caudicus who told Kvothe of this door, oddly similar to the one in the university's archives that he has a strong fascination with.

So, with all that being said, I believe the riddle suggests that whatever is inside the box, it is part of the seven things needed to open the Lackless family's door of stone. Though this might answer your question partially, it's certainly something to think about.